# Incapaz de enviar parametros por función

Tags: javascript

Rehaciendo una pregunta sobre un "Simon Says", copié el código completo de la respuesta, la cual funcionaba perfectamente, simplemente por el hecho de practicar.

Intenté hacerlo de otra forma, pero he llegado a un punto en el que no se puede avanzar.

```js
let lvl = 0;
let sub = 0;
let lst = 1;
let timeOutLight = null;
let sec = new Array(10).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));

function startGame(){
  //esconder botón
  var btn = document.querySelector('.boton');
    btn.classList.add('hide');

  let col = getColors();

  lightSec(lvl, sec, col);
}

function getColors(){
  const red = document.querySelector('.red');
  const yel = document.querySelector('.yellow');
  const gre = document.querySelector('.green');
  const blu = document.querySelector('.blue');
  const wit = document.querySelector('.withe');

  const col = {red, yel, gre, blu, wit};

  return col;
}

function lightSec(lvl, sec, col){
  for(var i=0;i<=lvl;i++){
    const sec_col = changeNumToCol(sec[i]);
    setTimeout(() => turnOnColor(sec_col, col),1000 * i);
  }
  addClickEvents(col);
}

function changeNumToCol(sec){
  switch(sec){
    case 0:
      return 'red'
    case 1:
      return 'yel'
    case 2:
      return 'gre'
    case 3:
      return 'blu'
    case 4:
      return 'wit'
  }
}

function turnOnColor(sec_col, col){
  col[sec_col].classList.add('light');
  setTimeout(() => turnOffColor(sec_col, col), 350);
}

function turnOffColor(sec_col, col){
  col[sec_col].classList.remove('light');
}

function addClickEvents(col){
  col.red.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.yel.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.gre.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.blu.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.wit.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
}

function delClickEvents(col){
  col.red.removeEventListener('click', selectColor);
  col.yel.removeEventListener('click', selectColor);
  col.gre.removeEventListener('click', selectColor);
  col.blu.removeEventListener('click', selectColor);
  col.wit.removeEventListener('click', selectColor);
}

function selectColor(ev){
  const colorName = ev.target.dataset.color;
  const colorNumb = changeColorToNumber(colorName);

  //turnOnColor(colorName);
  if(colorNumb === sec[sub]){
    sub++;

    if(sub>lvl){
      delClickEvents(col);
      lvl++;
      sub=0;

      timeOutLight = setTimeout(lightSec, 1500);
    }

    if (lvl === (lst + 1)) {
      winGame();
    }
    else{
      loseGame();
    }
  }
}

function changeColorToNumber(colorName){
  switch(colorName){
    case 'red':
      return 0
    case 'yel':
      return 1
    case 'gre':
      return 2
    case 'blu':
      return 3
    case 'wit':
      return 4
  }
}

function winGame(){
  delClickEvents();
  clearTimeout(timeOutLight);
  console.log('ganaste');
}

function loseGame(){
  delClickEvents();
  clearTimeout(timeOutLight);
  alert('perdiste');
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gameboard{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

.polen{
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: calc(0% - 50px);
  left: calc(-20% - 200px);
}

.box{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px  solid black ;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.uno{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.767);
  position: relative;
}

.dos{
  background-color:  rgb(49, 122, 55);
}

.tres{
  background-color: rgb(213, 224, 46) ;
  position: relative;
}

.cuatro{
  background-color: rgb(194, 13, 13);
}

.petado{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:50% ;
}

.petado.light{
  background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
}

.petado.dark{
  background-color:rgb(195, 197, 48);
}

.petaun{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

.petaun.light{
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
}


.petaun.dark{
  background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
}

.petatre{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

.petatre.light{
  background-color: rgb(198, 253, 201);
}


.petatre.dark{
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 74);
}

.petacua{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius:60% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.petacua.light{
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255); 
}

.petacua.dark{
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 211);
}

.polen{
  position:absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: calc(50% - 33px);
  left:calc(50% - 33px);
}

.polen.light{
  background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127)
}

.polen.dark{
  background-color:rgb(207, 205, 205);
}

.boton{
  position:absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: calc(50% - 31px);
  left:calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.boton.hide{
  display: none;
}

.boton:hover{
  border: 1px solid rgb(10, 10, 10);
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-style: italic;
}

.boton:focus{
  outline:0;
}

.resultado{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.resultados{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>009</title>
  <script src="js/009.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/009.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gameboard">

    <div class="box uno light" >
      <div class='red petaun' data-color="red" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box dos light">
      <div class="yellow petado" data-color="yel"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box tres light" >
      <div class="green petatre" data-color="gre"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box cuatro light" >
      <div class="blue petacua" data-color="blu"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="withe polen" data-color="wit"></div>

    <button class="boton btnEmpezar" onclick="startGame()">Empezar!</button>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hay un error sobre `ev.target: undefined`.

En la función `addClickEvents()` no mando ningún parámetro al llamar a la función `selectColor`, por tanto, `ev.target` estará indefinido, sino, haría referencia al elemento clicado.

Hasta aquí bien.

Lo malo es que, cuando le quito el parámetro `col`, y clico en el `div` iluminado, se rompe la cadena porque no envío a la función addClickEvents el parámetro 'col'.

He tratado de poner la variable `col` fuera de las funciones, para que sea una variable global, como `lvl`, `sub`, etc...; pero tampoco me funcionó.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Algo me falla al pulsar "Empezar", pero me parece que no es el error por el que preguntas

Comment: Me parece que si, el error lo arroja nada mas pulsarlo. Si es ev.target undefined, ese so lo que pregunto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando pulsas el botón para empezar a jugar, se ejecuta la función `startGam` que a su vez llama a `lightSec`, que a su vez llama a:

```
function addClickEvents(col){
  col.red.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.yel.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.gre.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.blu.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
  col.wit.addEventListener('click', selectColor(col));
}
```

Asumo que lo que realmente querías era algo como

```
function addClickEvents(col){
  col.red.addEventListener('click', event => selectColor(col));
  col.yel.addEventListener('click', event => selectColor(col));
  col.gre.addEventListener('click', event => selectColor(col));
  col.blu.addEventListener('click', event => selectColor(col));
  col.wit.addEventListener('click', event => selectColor(col));
}
```

Y que se podría mejorar a:

```
function addClickEvents(col){
  const selectColorFunction = event => selectColor(col, event);
  col.red.addEventListener('click', selectColorFunction);
  col.yel.addEventListener('click', selectColorFunction);
  col.gre.addEventListener('click', selectColorFunction);
  col.blu.addEventListener('click', selectColorFunction);
  col.wit.addEventListener('click', selectColorFunction);
}
```

Lo que te permitiría cambiar la firma de la función así:

```
function selectColor(col, ev){ ...}
```

Comment: Ahora, con los cambios que me recomendaste, haciendo pruebas, en la function `selectColor` si pongo (col, ev) `col` lo muestra como undefined. Si por el contrario declaro (ev, col), es el ev.target el que es undefined.